# Javascript forEach non blocking query

Tags: javascript, sails.js

In my controller (sails.js) I have a array, that contains a list of IDs.

Those are the IDs from a another table. I need to pull each record with that ID, and send it to user.

So far I have made this code:

```
     suggestions.forEach(function (element, index, array){
                    Suggester.findOne({
                    "id": element.suggester_id
                    },function(err,docs){
                        suggesterResults.push(docs);
                        console.log("I am adding to array: " + docs);
                        if (index === array.length - 1) {
                            completeSend(suggesterResults);
                        }
                    });
                })
    ...
    function completeSend (results) {
        console.log("I am in complete send method"  + results)
        return res.send(results, 200);
    }
```

That works, but it looks like a cheat. It looks to me this is blocking code, and that is not acceptable. Is there a usual way of doing things in this situation?

Comment: Sounds like a job for promises. Look it up :)

Comment: The complete code that I posted is within .done already :)

Comment: *"It looks to me this is blocking code..."* That depends a lot on what `Suggester.findOne` does. If it's async (and it certainly looks like it), then the `forEach` blocks for a small fraction of a millisecond at most, I should think; then `findOne` triggers its callbacks **later** when it's finished each of those lookups.

Comment: that `.findOne()` method runs synchronously ?

Comment: This looks like MongoDB, if so just get all the records with `find` and the `$in` operator

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. yes, this is part of a very large promise, actually that is a last one in chain. Would you agree that it should not block to much?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, it looks like MongoDB, but it is not. I will check your suggestion as well :)

Comment: Then what DB are you using ?

Comment: This is Sails.js, and the database is PostgreSQL

Comment: Seriously, I refuse to believe that's Postgre ?

Comment: Anyway, it should be done like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g3qew3e6/**

Comment: @adeneo take a look http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM  :)

Comment: I'm already reading it, sails uses [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline), which has promises and methods to query the entire set built in. It's just really inefficient to query a DB for one single record in a loop.

Comment: The correct way to write it is something like `Suggester.find({id: suggestions.map(x => x.suggester_id)}).then(completeSend);` - sends a single query, takes one line, no dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of doing this would be

```
Suggester.find({
    id: suggestions.map(function(s) { return s.suggester_id; })
})
.then(completeSend);
```

You call `find` once, and pass an array of IDs, once that's done, `completeSend` will be called with the array of results.

---

You mentioned all of this is already being a part of a promise chain, in which case having a `.then()` there is bad practice (don't nest `.then()` calls!)

If that's the case, then the correct way would be:

```
// Some promise chain logic here
.then(function(/* suggestions? */) {
    return Suggester.find({
        id: suggestions.map(function(s) { return s.suggester_id; })
    });
})
.then(completeSend);
```

Comment: This answer is the only reasonable way to solve this problem in your case in my humble opinion - both other answers suffer from [the select n+1 problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue). They're both valuable as they explain important concepts but this is definitely what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

With Promises:

```
Promise.all(suggestions.map(function(suggestion) {
    return Suggester.findOne({"id": suggestion.suggester_id});
})
.then(completeSend);
```

### Lets explain each line:

```
Promise.all(suggestions.map(function(suggestion) {
    return Suggester.findOne({"id": suggestion.suggester_id});
})
```

Map the suggestions array into a new array of promises. `findOne` returns a promise with the future result of the query.

`Promise.all()` is a static method that takes an array of promises, and returns a single promise that resolves when all of the promises in the array resolve successfully. That promise resolves **with an array of all resolved values, in the original order**, which happens to be exactly what you want.

```
.then(completeSend);
```

The promise this `.then` is called is the one returned from `Promise.all()`, so it's the equivalent of calling `completeSend()` with the array of all `docs` items, after all of the promises resolved.

Comment: WOW...I can't wait to give this a try :). Will let you know how it go.

Comment: @Wexoni note that my other answer is more correct than this.

Comment: As I noted in the comments in the question, Sails.js does use [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline), which includes Bluebird and supports promises using Bluebird natively.

Answer (score 1):

If `findOne` completes asynchronously, and it certainly looks like it does, then that `forEach` will block for maybe a fraction of a millisecond. **Later**, `findOne` will call each of the callbacks, when each of its lookups completes. From a blocking perspective, that code is fine, given the proviso that `findOne` completes asynchronously.

**But**, the code has a different issue: You're assuming the callbacks will happen *in order*, by doing this:

```
if (index === array.length - 1) {
    completeSend(suggesterResults);
}
```

You can't make that assumption unless `findOne` documents it (I looked on the sails.js site; couldn't find any documentation for `findOne` other than an entry in a bullet list that didn't say anything). The callbacks could arrive out-of-sequence, for instance if one lookup is faster than one before it.

Instead, you'll want to track *how many* callbacks you've gotten, and call `completeSend` when you've gotten the same number as the requests you've made, rather than relying on the index.

If `suggesterResults` is blank when you start and nothing is going to modify `suggestions` while the calls are outstanding, you can use its `length`:

```
suggestions.forEach(function (element, index, array){
    Suggester.findOne({
    "id": element.suggester_id
    },function(err,docs){
        suggesterResults.push(docs);
        console.log("I am adding to array: " + docs);
        if (suggesterResults.length === array.length) {
            completeSend(suggesterResults);
        }
    });
})
```

But if either of those caveats isn't true, you're better off with a counter:

```
var waitingon = 0;
suggestions.forEach(function (element, index, array){
    ++waitingon;
    Suggester.findOne({
    "id": element.suggester_id
    },function(err,docs){
        suggesterResults.push(docs);
        console.log("I am adding to array: " + docs);
        if (--waitingon === 0) {
            completeSend(suggesterResults);
        }
    });
})
```

That *looks* like a race condition, but it isn't because this is a single-threaded environment. All of the `forEach` callbacks will happen before the first `findOne` callback does, so `waitingon` will rise to the appropriate level before we start decrementing it. (This also allows for the possibilty, which seems unlikely, that `suggestions` is sparse.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair enough. Wexoni: same question

Comment: Fair enough :) I dont ignore them in the real code, but skipped them here to make code more readable. But, you got point... It should be done the same way, always